# GraphLab Installation Issue

Tags: path, installation, graphlab

I am trying to install GraphLab on windows 10, however towards the end of the installation I receive this error:

> Unable to activate conda environment "gl-env":
>       Deactivating environment "C:\Users\mbaco\Anaconda2"...
>   Activating environment "C:\Users\mbaco\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env"...
>
> The input line is too long. 
>   "PATH_NO_SCRIPTS=C:\Users\mbaco\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env;C:\Users\marc\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\Scripts;C:\Users\marc\Anaconda2\envs\gl-env\Library\bin;C:\Usersmarc\Anaconda2;;C:\ProgramData\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Program
>   Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS
>   Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;
>   ............ ETC" was unexpected at this time.

Any help in solving this would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You need to reduce the length of your system path variable. Delete paths not in use to make the path variable has length shorter than 2047 characters.